# strtotime with timezone getting incorrect day in php

Tags: php, timezone, strtotime

I'm using this code to get UTC times with strtotime:

```
strtotime("12am America/Sao_Paulo");
```

But I noticed a terrible flaw to it:

Since timezone "America/Sao_Paulo" is GMT-3, it's getting exactly that (GMT) 12am -3, but if it's after 9 PM in GMT-3 timezone, it's already the next day in GMT, so it gets the time for the wrong day

Example: It's 10:00 PM on day 21 of December

`strtotime("12am America/Sao_Paulo");` returns me the time 12:00 AM of day 22, which still didn't even happen in GMT-3

Expected output was 12:00 AM of the day 21

How can I fix it without changing whole server default timezone?

Comment: call `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');` before `strtotime('12am');` [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: But then, wouldn't it affect all other times after it's called? There are still some times I need in GMT on that site

Comment: only affects your current script

Comment: It runs within foreach blocks and some of them are in one timezone, some in the other and there might be even more timezones in the future, so I was avoiding the changing default timezone, does it keeps the setting on all the loops after it's called or does it rever after each loop?

Comment: you can create a  `new DateTime` with a specific timezone and then get the timestamp